# How to programmatically add a field to a view depending on another field and reorder fields then

Tags: views

I broke a site yesterday using views global php, even if it was working in the preview, so I'm a bit nervious about that php in database and I'm trying to implement the same thing with Views API.

Depending on the key value of a hidden field in the current display, I need to put a custom text. Something like (global php version) :

```
if( isset($data) && isset($data->field_field_statut_depart) ) {

  switch(  $data->field_field_statut_depart[0]['raw']['value'] ) {

    case 1: 
      $text = 'ABC';
      break;
    case 2: 
      $text = 'DEF';
      break;
    //and so on

  }
  print $text;
}
```

I'm trying to build it with `hook_views_pre_view(&$view, &$display_id, &$args)` but I can't find the required `field_statut_depart` value in  `dpm($view)`.

Maybe it's not the right hook ?

EDIT : after applying solution described in the answers below (views_post_execute hook) and 12 hours running, I'm facing a strange behaviour : the changes made by  views_post_execute hook are not stable : after clearing caches, they are visible for a while but raw data (without my function applied) is displayed then ! I'm afraid it's still not the right place to do that. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try the [views_post_execute](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_post_execute/7) hook.

Otherwise there is a reduced list of hooks used for views rendering at the [bottom of the Views Hooks API page](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/group/views_hooks/7#comment-49128).

It is a little hidden but I have used it many times and you may find a solution to your issue there.

Comment: please have a look at the question, savoyard ;) The view does not display the processed data but the raw values after a while !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kartsims suggestion, this did the trick :

```
function MODULE_views_post_execute(&$view) {
  if ($view->name == 'foo' && $view->current_display == 'bar') {
    //dpm($view);
    foreach ($view->result as $result) {
      //dpm($result);
      if (isset($result->field_field_statut_depart)) {

        switch($result->field_field_statut_depart[0]['raw']['value'] ) {
          case 1: 
            $text = 'ABC';
            break;
          case 2: 
            $text = 'DEF';
            break;
          //and so on
        }  
        $result->field_field_statut_depart[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = $text;
      }

      if (isset($result->field_commerce_stock)) {

        $result->field_commerce_stock[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = '';

        if($result->field_commerce_stock[0]['raw']['value'] < 6 ) {
          $result->field_commerce_stock[0]['rendered']['#markup'] = $result->field_commerce_stock[0]['raw']['value'].' items remaining';
        }  
      }
    }   
  }
}
```